# How can I use results of POST call to API to do another POST call

Tags: ios, swift

In a project I am working on, I am calling an https API with a POST request which gives me results as a JSON. I am doing the call with AlamoFire, and parsing this with SwiftJSON.

All goes according to plans, and the JSON is received and can be parsed. But now I want to use the values from the received JSON, and immediately do another call to the same API with a different path and use those values as parameters in the call.

At the moment I am posting a `NSNotification` and when that `NSNotification` is received I do the POST call to the other path for the details of the data. This works, but not very consistently.

I think that sometimes the data gets in the wrong sequence and the parameters might not be correct. About 80% of the time it works as expected.

Is this the way to work? Or is this not correct to do it with `NSNotification`? Any insights on this might help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using this notification pattern correctly, it should work 100% of the time, not 80% of the time. Or, more accurately, if the network connection or server response fails for reasons outside of your control, you should handle it gracefully. If you need help on that problem, update your question with [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we'll see if we can help you.

In terms of a more efficient way to handle this overall process, the typical pattern would be to initiate the second request from inside the `response` closure of the first request.

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, url1, parameters: parameters1).response { request, response, data, error in

    // create url2 and/or parameters2

    Alamofire.request(.POST, url2, parameters: parameters2).response { request, response, data, error in
        // do something with second request
    }
}
```

One would generally only use the notification pattern if there is no reliable relationship between the two processes (e.g. when the first request was initiated, it has no reasonable way of possibly knowing which (if any) secondary request(s) will need to react in response to the first request.

Comment: I have adapted this pattern (seemed much cleaner as what I was doing before). However it did still not work properly, but after cleaning up my code for posting an edit to my question I seem to have fixed it. :) The problem was in the unreliable way of looping through my results JSON in the end. Thanks for the help!